# Battery circle like Battery Widget Reborn

Tags: android, canvas, battery

I am trying to make draw a circle based on the battery percentage. I have the following code:

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, conf);

Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

circle = new Path();
circle.addCircle(100, 100, level, Direction.CW);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawPath(circle, mPaint);
```

I am trying to get similar to Battery Widget Reborn, where its a circle path drawn based on a percentage, could someone please help.

Edit:

below is a shot of what i am trying to accomplish

[image: image of the percentage circle]

Comment: So what does your code currently do? It looks like it should draw a circle with radius proportionate to the level. Does it? Also, you may want to either include a screenshot or describe better what Battery Widget Reborn does, it'll save others from looking it up(or just ignoring the question).

Comment: I shall edit it now with an image, it currently draws a full circle but resizes it depending on the value of level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `Path.addArc()`. You just have to define the bounds of the enclosing rectangle, the start angle, and how many degrees to sweep.

Something like:

```
RectF box = new RectF(0,0,bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight());
float sweep = 360 * level * 0.01f;
circle.addArc(box, 0, sweep);
```

Comment: Please look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697189/fill-color-on-bitmap-in-android?noredirect=1#comment30999957_20697189

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did not work for me, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this class as a full working example. You can also add the text in the view, but that goes beyond the question...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {

    Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG |
                Paint.DITHER_FLAG |
                Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);

        int size = 200;
        int radius = 190;
        int delta = size - radius;
        int arcSize = (size - (delta / 2)) * 2;
        int percent = 42;

        //Thin circle
        canvas.drawCircle(size, size, radius, mPaint);

        //Arc
        mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#33b5e5"));
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        RectF box = new RectF(delta,delta,arcSize,arcSize);
        float sweep = 360 * percent * 0.01f;
        canvas.drawArc(box, 0, sweep, false, mPaint);

    }

}
```