# Meter like UI with animation Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Anyone have idea how to create Meter like Measurement UI like this 
[image]

When an activity creates, animation should occur in the meter and percentage/digit
 will show..

Let me know if you know article or tutorial which explains how to do this. It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of projects that achieve this on GitHub.

Here is one I've found https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do this with `Path.addArc()`. You just have to define the bounds of the enclosing rectangle, the start angle, and how many degrees to sweep.

[Battery circle like Battery Widget Reborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988701/battery-circle-like-battery-widget-reborn)